# Can't access my repos in VSTS using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to access my repositories hosted in VSTS as well each branch in the respective repository. Below is my code

```
 public class VSTSController : ApiController
{
    const String c_collectionUri = "https://****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection";
    const String c_projectName = "****";
    const String c_repoName = "****";

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/VSTS/Init")]
    public string Init()
    {

        // Interactively ask the user for credentials, caching them so the user isn't constantly prompted
        VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
        creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

        // Connect to VSTS
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(c_collectionUri), creds);

        // Get a GitHttpClient to talk to the Git endpoints
        GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

        // Get data about a specific repository
        var repo = gitClient.GetRepositoryAsync(c_projectName, c_repoName).Result;
        return repo.RemoteUrl;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an exception `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`.
How to authenticate to VSTS REST APIs? I couldn't understand following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet).

Comment: With web app, you need to use OAuth or specify the credential (Token or alternative account) directly. (As Daniel said)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is telling you exactly why you're having a problem implementing this in a WebAPI application: `// Interactively ask the user for credentials, caching them so the user isn't constantly prompted`

It can't interactively prompt for credentials, so it fails.

The authentication [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples#authenticating-vsts) gives several samples demonstrating different authentication methods. The easiest is probably the Personal Access Token:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
```

where `pat` is a variable containing a valid Personal Authentication Token.

However, you probably want to ultimately implement OAuth authentication, which is thoroughly documented and [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) is provided.